# Об олимпиадах и морали

Tags: обсуждение

Вопрос простой - о том, насколько соответствует духу (не тому, который "Дух сообщества") ruSO упоминание в ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1530684/228791 ссылки на больше двух десятков решений разных олимпиадных задач (e-olymp, acmp, timus)?

Comment: a в чём именно видится проблема наличия ссылки при достаточно развёрнутом ответе?

Comment: эмм.. вы клоните к тому, что на ruSO нельзя давать ответы и подкреплять их ссылками на решения?

Comment: И, в чем конкретно вы тут видите проблему?

Comment: На самом деле вопрос не такой бессмысленный, как многим показался. Прочтите-ка ещё раз цитату из ответа: *"Так что по результатам пишу ответ на ruSO и занимаюсь другими делами... теперь еще и закинул решение (давненько не делал, кстати...) на [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/tree/master/olymp)."* И ссылка ведёт на ответы к домашке...

Comment: @Зонтик, и в чем проблема? Какое правило или "заповедь" нарушены?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ По ссылке можно найти больше 20 решений других задач с олимпиадных сайтов.

Comment: Их надо вопросами/ответами на руСО запостить, если проблема в том, что они где-то на стороне сейчас.